# Javascript nested for loop not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop

This is weird, I'm having issues with simple nested for loops in javascript.

My code is like this:

```
var a = 0, b = 2048;
var i = 0, l = 2048;

for(; a < b; a++) {
    for(; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(a, b, i, l);
    }
}
```

So while, I'm expecting an output like this `(0..2047), 2048, (0..2047), 2048`, I'm having this output: `0, 2048, 0..2047, 2048` where the first variable: `a` doesn't simply iterate from 0 to 2047.
Rephrasing the concept: while the inner loop iterates correctly, the outer one is executed only once at index 0.

I'm sure it's a simple and silly issue, but I can't really spot that..

**COMMENT**

Thank you all for finding this issue, it's incredible how I couldn't see that. I'm accepting simon's answer because it seems cleaner and more elegant to me:

- He doesn't reinitialize variable as in `for(var i = 0;...)` but just reset it
- He includes the variable reset in the for statement rather than after every iteration
- He doesn't declare variables `var a = 0, i = 0` and then reset that in every for statement
- He uses the regular increment
- He declares every variable at the beginning of the snippet instead of declaring them at different times in the execution

Thanks again!

Comment: its simply because when i reaches 2048 the outer loop cannot get executed again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize i every time before inner iteration:

```
var a = 0, b = 2048;
var i, l = 2048;

for(; a < b; a++) {
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(a, b, i, l);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't reload `i` to `0` between `a` loops. Here the fix :

```
var a = 0, b = 2048;
var i = 0, l = 2048;

for(a = 0; a < b; a++) {
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(a, b, i, l);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because you never reset i, so the inner loop will only happen during the first iteration on the outer loop. Thereafter i will always be greater than l.

Try this:

```
var a = 0, b = 2048;
var i = 0, l = 2048;

for(; a < b; a++) {
    for(; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(a, b, i, l);
    }
    i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the loop goes like this:

for a = 0; itarates while i becomes 2048.
then for a =1 the i is 2048, thus i not < l and thus not getting into the loop again.

```
var a = 0, b = 2048;

for(; a < b; a++) {
    var i = 0, l = 2048;
    for(; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(a, b, i, l);
    }
}
```

I believe this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

<del>This is a scope problem. Variables `a` and `i` are not defined in the scope of your for loops.</del> Define them inside this way:

```js
var b = 2048,
    l = 2048;

for(var a = 0; a < b; a = a + 1) {
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i = i + 1) {
        console.log(a, b, i, l);
    }
}
```

*edit:* squint is absolutely correct, JavaScript doesn't use block scope, for which I mistook as the issue. Although, you should always consider defining the variables that increment inside the declaration of your for loops to eliminate confusion/ambiguity.

Comment: It's not a scope problem. Your code doesn't change the variable scope at all. The only problem was with the failure to reset `i` in the loop, which your answer does fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try one loop

```js
var a = 0, b = 2048;
var i = 0, l = 2048;

for(; a <= b&&i<=l; a++,i++) {
    console.log(a, b, i, l);
}
```

With two loops it i is never reset and so only get iterated once, hence the result of 
`0, 2048, 0..2047, 2048`

Comment: this won't produce the expected output